# phpMyAdmin auto insert and display only date

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a table with a date-type field

- browser transform: `text/plain: dateformat`
- transform option: `0,'%d-%b-%Y','local'`

When I execute my query it stores 01-Jan-1970 (default value) and on page it shows me `0000-00-00`

What I want to do is to store in database and in page only the date and dateformat `Y-m-d` like `27.02.2016`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you clarify? What query are you executing?

Comment: I'm trying to insert in my database a blog post with some fields and a date filed to show the post date. The current date should automatcly be set when the post is added into database, but instead i get the 0000.00.00 or the 01-Jan-1970 result in the database date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of things going on that I should address first.

The phpMyAdmin transform feature affects how you insert or view data *from within phpMyAdmin only*. It doesn't change how the data is stored internally with MySQL and it doesn't change how other applications interact with MySQL. So when you talk about displaying in your blog or storing in MySQL, those aren't affected by the transformations you've configured.

Next, you don't appear to be setting the post date, which means you're probably getting '0000-00-00 00:00:00' stored in the column. The exception would be if you allow NULL or set a default value. You can also get zeroes if you insert invalid dates.

The appropriate thing to is use the MySQL type and format the display on output -- either in SQL or in your application; I usually do it in my application. How to do that will depend on which programming language your application uses.

When inserting, you can use `NOW()` to insert the current time without having to compute it yourself.